# Can't install python bcs it says this version already exists but this version doesn't exist

Tags: python, installation, uninstallation

I can't uninstall python 3.6.6 bcs that says 'No python installation was detected' and can't install python 3.6.0 bcs it says 'One version of this product is already installed' and I don't know what to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that generally 'python' indicates Python 2.xx. You are trying to remove python, which may not exist, but you are trying to install python3. (This may be different in Windows though)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install python 2.7 and try to uninstall python 3.6. You might have deleted the files of python 3.6 that's why you are getting that error

Comment: idk what you mean